# Firebase .on('value, function(){} ) executing twice with one push

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm noticing something that I don't understand.  I have the following "on" query setup in my code.  When I 'push' a child to a lower level, it appears to me that the "on" callback function is getting raised twice.

```
fb.child('Question').on('value',function(ss){ console.log('on called'); });
```

Example Structure:

> Question
>
> > ----> Answers
> >
> > > ----> {Answer 1} : { answer object } 
> > >       ----> {Answer 2} : { answer object }

I'm adding "answers" via the "push" function so the "key" for the answer is the uniquely created firebase "unique id".

```
fb.child('Question/Answers').push({the answer object});
```

At this point I'm only pushing new "answers", no update or set.  What I'm seeing is that when I push a new "answer object", the "on" function is getting called twice.

I have double checked, and I don't have the "on" event handler attached more than once.  I have also check to be sure the "push" is only getting called one time.

Is this the correct behavior?  I'm "guessing" that the push is "inserting" the child and then "set"ing the answer object, which is causing the on to fire twice?  But this doesn't sound right to me?

Obviously I'm fairly new to Firebase, so not sure if this is by design or not.  But it make me nervous that big picture I'm running the "on" code more than once per single update?

Comment: Can you try creating a JSFiddle or similar that reproduces the behavior? That would make it a bit easier to get to the bottom of what's going on.

Comment: Hi Dan. Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: @RobDiMarco I will try and work something up this weekend.  I guess my main question was "should the push method raise the 'on' event twice".  I'm assuming by your response that it should not be doing that. Correct?

Comment: @Kato Thanks for the input, and I do want to learn how to best use this site.  But I'm unclear as to how my question was not unclear.  I thought I had laid it out in as simple as terms as possible.  I stated the problem and gave examples.  Just trying to learn.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for asking. To clarify, you're not asking a question, you're asking why an odd behavior occurs. And it is odd. Something is executing twice which shouldn't be. The incorrect condition is very clear in your question and you've done a good job with it. What is unclear is how we can reproduce the condition to recommend a fix. To do that, we need a repro that helps us see all the nuances of your specific use case.

Comment: @Kato thanks for the input.  And yes I will see if I can reproduce the problem in a simplified form.  But I guess I was looking for confirmation that this was in fact an odd behavior.   Being new to Firebase, I wasn't sure if this was or was not a desired behavior, I could make arguments either way in my head.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue with firebase on 'value' event. It happens because of multiple listeners are attached for the same event, on page load or reauthentication etc.

The solution is to remove the existing listener before attaching new listener.

In firebase call `off()` event before `on()` event to fix this.

In this scenario,

```
fb.child('Question').off();
fb.child('Question').on('value',function(ss){ console.log('on called'); });
```

will fix the issue

Comment: I had to call `off()` inside the `response`. i.e. `fb.child('Question').on('value', function(ss){ 
   console.log('on called'); 
   fb.child('Question').off();
}`

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to firebase, faced the same issue as yours. Found out that this is expected if you used `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`.

> when you write a server-side timestamp, the client gets two events.
>
> The first event that fires is a local estimate of the server
> timestamp, based on the local time, and the detected latency between
> the client and server.
>
> The second event is the actual value as the server determined it.
>
> If you're writing the timestamp to a new node, the first of these
> events will typically be a child_added, while the second will be a
> child_changed.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2461
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.ThenableReference#on